# What is the best way to secure login proccess via ajax

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, authentication, zend-auth

when you post form via ajax, you can read password in plain text there. I thing that is security issue. Which possibilities are to hide password or disallowed to read it in firebug console for example?

Comment: Using HTTPS is your best option.

Comment: u can use ajax post calls to prevent this

Comment: why do you think the password for a "normal" request would not be readable in firebug/dev tools? even with https it is.

Comment: @Hussain Akhtar Wahid - you can read post params as well

Comment: @martin - so that isn't security issue?

Comment: @tomasr well, no more than e.g. key loggers are. you can't really control whats happening on the local machine, you can only offer a secure transmission (https).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is really secure when you don't use HTTPS. Attackers could intercept your Ajax JS code and do a man-in-the-middle attack on your login process.

Use HTTPS.